# PHP Todo CheckList Checked Feature

Tags: php

I need help with a PHP ToDo List. I have most of it working except for the check box to move it from a completed list to a still need to do list. here is the code I have so far:

For the edit screen:

```
%% views/header.html %%
        <h1>{{$title}}</h1>
        <div class='inputs'>
        <form action="@@todo/update@@" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{$todo['id']}}" />
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="{{$todo    ['description']}}" />
            <label for="done">Done?:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="done" name="done" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        <form>
    </div>
    <p><a href="@@index@@"><< Back</a></p>
    %% views/footer.html %%
```

For the todo.inc file:

```
<?php
include_once "include/util.inc";
include_once "models/todo.inc";
function safeParam($arr, $index, $default) {
    if ($arr && isset($arr[$index])) {
        return $arr[$index];
    }
    return $default;
}
function get_view($params) {
    $id = safeParam($params, 0, false);
    if ($id === false) {
        die("No todo id specified");
    }
    $todo = findToDoById($id);
    if (!$todo) {
        die("No todo with id $id found.");
    }
    // @formatter:off
    renderTemplate(
        "views/todo_view.inc",
        array(
            'title' => 'Viewing To Do',
            'todo' => $todo
        )
    );
    // @formatter:on
}
function get_list($params) {
    $todos = findAllCurrentToDos();
    $dones = findAllDoneToDos();
    // @formatter:off
    renderTemplate(
        "views/index.inc",
        array(
            'title' => 'To Do List',
            'todos' => $todos,
            'dones' => $dones
        )
    );
    // @formatter:on
}
function get_edit($params) {
    $id = safeParam($params, 0, false);
    if (!$id) {
        die("No todo specified");
    }
    $todo = findToDoById($id);
    if (!$todo) {
        die("No todo found.");
    }
    // @formatter:off
    renderTemplate(
        "views/todo_edit.inc",
        array(
            'title' => 'Editing To Do',
            'todo' => $todo
        )
    );
    // @formatter:on
}

function post_add($params) {
    if (!isset($_POST['description'])) {
        die("no description given");
    }
    $description = htmlentities($_POST['description']);
    addToDo($description);
    redirectRelative("index");
}

function validate_present($elements) {
    $errors = '';
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$element])) {
            $errors .= "Missing $element\n";
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

function post_update($params) {
    $errors = validate_present(array('id', 'description', 'done'));
    if ($errors) {
        die($errors);
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $done = $_POST['done'];
    updateToDo($id, $description, $done);
    redirectRelative("todo/view/$id");
    }

function get_delete($params) {
    $id = safeParam($params, 0, false);
    if (!$id) {
        die("No todo specified");
    }
    $todo = findToDoById($id);
    if (!$todo) {
        die("No todo found.");
    }
    deleteToDo($id);
    redirectRelative("index");
}
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?  What is working, what isn't, any errors?

Comment: When the item it marked completed from the 'Current To Do Section' it works perfectly and dropws it down to the 'Past To Do' Section. When I take an item from the 'Past To Do Section' try to edit it to update the checkbox status to a current to do, its breaks. Can you help? I get the error ' Missing Done'

Comment: Does anyone have any advice? I can send files if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in these two functions.

```
function validate_present($elements) {
    $errors = '';
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$element])) {
            $errors .= "Missing $element\n";
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

function post_update($params) {
    $errors = validate_present(array('id', 'description', 'done'));
    if ($errors) {
        die($errors);
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $done = $_POST['done'];
    updateToDo($id, $description, $done);
    redirectRelative("todo/view/$id");
}
```

You are attempting to validate that `done` exists in `validate_present` when called by `post_update`.  `done` obviously cannot exists since it is not sent to the server when the checkbox is not checked.  The `$_POST` does not even contain that variable, so it returns that element is missing (since it technically is). I would leave `validate_present` alone and change `post_update` as follows:

```
function post_update($params) {
    $errors = validate_present(array('id', 'description'));
    if ($errors) {
        die($errors);
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $done = (isset($_POST['done'])? 1 : 0);
    updateToDo($id, $description, $done);
    redirectRelative("todo/view/$id");
}
```

Comment: Yes.. I am getting this error:Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TodoModel2\controllers\todo.inc on line 89 which leads back to $done = (is_set($_POST['done'])? 1 : 0);

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I changed my method while typing.  Should be, (isset($_POST['done'])? 1 : 0);  I am editing it in the answer as well.